# Exclude some text from search result in DRUPAL

Tags: php, drupal

Is it possible to exclude some words from the key words which the drupal search form uses?

For example I don't need results to be indexed with "search" word.

Answer (score 0):

First check out http://drupal.org/project/custom_search

It has a filter feature maybe that will do the trick.

If that does not work then Try this:

Create your own search form and don't use the drupal default search.

You can make your own search using the below api and the forms api.

http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--search--search.module/function/search_form/7

If you read the api you will notice variable $keys is the variable which will hold the search string so before you call the search function use regex and remove your keyword you wont' want .

All the best !

Cheers,
Visahl